# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in selenium when trying to run a test case

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Below is my simple testcase program:

```
    package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class myclass {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myclass dr= new myclass();
        dr.start();
        dr.select();
    }

    public void start(){

        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }

    public void select(){
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
    }

}
```

but it throws the below error everytime i run it:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mypackage.myclass.select(myclass.java:26)
    at mypackage.myclass.main(myclass.java:15)
```

The browser gets launched and the google home page is also displayed but the next action of selecting the gmail link doesnt happen and the error appears.
**tried this on different browsers(i.e. chrome) but error still persists

please help me with this i am new to selenium..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up "variable scope" in Java.

This line:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
```

is referencing:

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

which is never set as anything.

This should fix that error:

```
public void start(){
    driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
```

Also, class names should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "WebDriver" instance from the start() method which is already declared above ,if you use it then "WebDriver" declare globally is not in current scope of method start()

```
 package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class myclass {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myclass dr= new myclass();
        dr.start();
        dr.select();
    }

    public void start(){

        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }

    public void select(){
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
    }

}
```